# Checkpoint not found when placed in Shared Object Respository

Tags: hp-uft

I am able to move a checkpoint from local OR to shared OR but when the code is executed it fails to find the checkpoint located in the shared OR. Anyway I can make this happen-please help? 
*OR=Object Repository
Using HP UFT 11.53
***NOTE:*** My checkpoint code is NOT in the Action1 but in a separate .vbs file which I call from the Action1. Also I am NOT using the local OR at all only using shared OR.

Comment: I'm sure you question will benefit from showing us the code you're struggling with.

Comment: the code is very generic for example: Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebElement("Google Search").Check CheckPoint("Google Search"). So Google Search is a checkpoint that I am trying to verify which is seating under the shared OR. The code line will work if the checkpoint was seating under the local OR.

Answer (score 0):

Have you associated this separate .vbs script with the test?  If you're unaware of how to do this, I suggest you check this link:

http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/09/associate-function-library-to-qtp-script/